# JavaScript- Opening, Refreshing, and Accessing New Tabs

Tags: javascript, windows, search, reload

I am making a bot to do something that I am running from chrome's console. It is supposed to open a new tab of a certain link, and then refresh it for as long as it runs. After each refresh, it is supposed to use .getElementById to find something, and if it is found (it is a hyperlink), it is supposed to open the place where it links in a new tab. Here is what I have so far (riddled with errors, sorry).

```
var go = true;
var win = window.open("http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?id=1211749", "_blank");
//WIN IS NULL FOR SOME REASON
function doTheThing()
{
    //BECAUSE WIN IS NULL, NOT SURE IF WORKS
    win.location.reload();
    //BECAUSE WIN IS NULL, NOT SURE IF WORKS
    //MUST GRAB ELEMENT FROM THE OTHER REFRESHED WINDOW
    var x = win.document.getElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxUserAssetsPane_UserAssetsDataList_ctl00_AssetNameHyperLink");
    var n = x.search("Federation");
    //If the link title has "Federation" in it
    if (n > -1 && go == true)
    {
        var win = window.open(x, '_blank');
        //MAY NOT WORK SINCE THE OTHER WINDOW.OPEN DOES NOT WORK
        //Open the window
        if(win)
        {
            win.focus();
        //go to it
        }
        go = false;
        //Keep it from opening 1000 windows
    }
}
while (go == true)
{
    var zhuLi = setInterval(doTheThing, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [setInterval(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) function, not setTimeOut(...). If by any chance you want to exit out of setInterval loop, you can use [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval).

Comment: Thank you! I was also erroring at the var x = part because I couldn't find out how to access the document in the newly opened tab. Do you know how I could fix that?

Comment: @user3339797 No, I'm sorry. I've never done that and can't help you :(. And I suppose it should be a different question. But a quick search returned me [this query method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) with which you can query the tabs, or something? I've no idea... Sorry. But good luck!